# How do I view other people's screenshots on Steam?

Tags: steam

I can view my own screenshots just fine from my steam homepage, but I can't find other people's screenshots on their profile pages. Please help!

Answer (score 14):

To view your friend's screenshots, your friend must first have saved said screenshots (obviously).

*Firstly*, you must view their **Steam profile**.

*Secondly*, you must click **Screenshots** on their profile page. It looks like this:

[image]

It should then bring up a list of all of their screenshots for your viewing pleasure. It will look something like this:

[image]

This all depends on whether or not your friend has his or her screenshots set as Public, Friends Only, or Private. If you know for a fact your friend has some screenshots, but you can't see them, the chances are they are private.

Comment: Wish I had that many friends on Steam.